# Get page url from embeded JS script

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page that calls a JS file. Within that JS file I need to know what the URL of the HTML page is.

So far I have this.

HTML -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Within my main.js I have the following:

```
$(function() {
  $ = jQuery;
  window.remoteUser = "%globals_server_REMOTE_USER%";
  window.targetURL = "%globals_asset_url%";
  console.log(document.referrer);
});
```

I thought document.referrer would return the URL of the html page. However it returns a blank line in the console.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: scripts are added inside `<head>` tag (Best practice)

Comment: Nope, Just beofre the closing body tag is a good practice too (performance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
console.log(document.URL);
```

OR

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

since i read that it doesn't work in some versions of firefox

Answer (score 0):

`location.href`  used to get url the of page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

       jQuery("#url1").html(location.href);   

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r5kaxwwu/3/)